# marine animal tracking databases

Tags: marine-biology

Which databases you know that store data on tracking of marine animals?

I am interested particularly on mammals (for which I know meop storing data on sea lions) but also on fish schools (not sure they exist though).

Comment: could you explain what sort of information you need in more detail

Comment: I am interested in spatial tracking. Track animals' movements and vertical movements

Comment: One major tagging effort/database is the TOPP program-- "Tagging of Pelagic Predators". They track Pacific Blue Marlin, Mako Sharks, Whale Sharks, Salmon Sharks, Pacific Bluefin Tuna, White Sharks, Atlantic Bluefin Tuna, Northern Elephant Seals, and Leatherback Sea Turtles. I'm not sure if their data are publically available. 

Info here: http://gtopp.org/ and here: http://oceanview.pfeg.noaa.gov/TOPP/

Comment: WhaleNet is less pretty, but has older marine mammal tracking data: Gray Seal, Harbor Seals, Harp Seals, Harbor Porpoise; dolphins (archived) and whales (archived): http://whale.wheelock.edu/whalenet-stuff/stop_cover.html

Comment: Sea turtle tracks can be found at http://www.seaturtle.org/tracking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MoveBank.org](https://www.movebank.org/cms/movebank-main). It provides access to online animal tracking data (whales, turtles, seabirds, etc.). Some come with ancillary data like depth. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The [Animal Telemetry Network](https://atn.ioos.us/) (ATM) was "established to provide unity, stability and continuity to the national infrastructure that facilitates the collection, management and availability of this marine animal telemetry data. To accomplish its mission, the ATN is being implemented in three Phases and on these three foundational pillars: 1) Building Alliances and Collaborations, 2) Providing Telemetry Data Aggregation, Management, Display and Delivery, and 3) Funding High Priority Regional Baseline Animal Telemetry Observations." The network provides access to maps with data, will sometimes provide links to publicly available data, and provides point of contact for each dataset.